# How to customize HTML formatting with Vue 3 and Prettier?

Tags: eslint, vuejs3, prettier

I have setup a new Vue 3 project with Eslint and Prettier config.
But when reformatting the HelloWorld.vue I see something ugly like this

```html
        <a
          href="https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-babel"
          rel="noopener"
          target="_blank"
          >babel</a
        >
```

I want something more compact and still readable like this:

```html
        <a href="https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-babel" rel="noopener"
          target="_blank">babel</a>
```

I searched for a while and also tried out things like `"htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore"` but nothing helps.

.eslintrs.js

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/typescript/recommended',
    '@vue/prettier',
    '@vue/prettier/@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? ['error', {allow: ['warn', 'error']}] : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)', '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)'],
      env: {
        mocha: true,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

.prettierrc

```js
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "bracketSpacing": false,
  "printWidth": 120,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore"
}
```

### My Solution

That I wouldn't name an answer, because it doesn't solve the problem with Prettier.
**I don't use Prettier any more.**

This is my current `.eslintrc.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: ['plugin:vue/vue3-essential', '@vue/standard', '@vue/typescript/recommended'],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
  },
  rules: {
    'comma-dangle': ['error', 'always-multiline'],
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? ['error', { allow: ['warn', 'error'] }] : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'quotes': ['error', 'single'],
    'vue/html-quotes': ['error', 'double'],
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)', '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)'],
      env: {
        jest: true,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Together with IntelliJ, this configuration leads to code formatting that looks pretty for me...

Answer (score 0):

That formatting is controlled by Prettier's [`printWidth` option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width). Since you're seeing the wrapping occur even with a `printWidth` of 120, the problem is likely that the particular line that `<a>` is on exceeds 120 characters, including surrounding whitespace (as seen in this [demo](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAeeBbADgGwIbwB8AOlAARmoAmAlgG5k1UC8xIeWWbJ5FltdHnz7V6Q4SIHiJksaRkzRg+QsVTUeMgAsATnABmrEFpgwsAZyQB6KwHMaMLQFcARgDpIGK3SdwAVubevgC0YDg0VjB6cFZUcHRWWHhgANZ4tnCBAKQALAAMPjFhNMG4TvZQwS54LnA4bGR6OEZQEBBYCHA6DTB4OhkwRgD6LvhQKdzVtTioVniEs1IqqhSLcryqa8obElvSIrHrwnsqJ1CzmLgEcDwgADQg7TA00ObIoH06EADuAAp9CDeKDwOG+eAAnm8Hi4dMkUnAYABlJJgGhQWzIKK+B5wDC1KhxKgAGTw6Kc6TgADEIDoMARnujkOwnDAIPdjDAMDgAOpaByZFFwRGAhz0Bzgpk0WytPTstHmLowX6w2x05D6EEKh4BAAeACFYakEYi8Bg4ES0XBMTpsSBdYi0bYcHAAIpOCDwdWauAPJI6BU6JlTOrsrA6NEwblMRzIACMACY8r6vgrubCsEyw5kunQrQ8AI7u+DK9pA9jmYJQOBwQnsvSFmh6ZXpNVIDU4LUgBUYGhejs+ruO51uj1WpBYge9FxRqgxpDxh5RPA0cLogDCEAwrZAmQArOynAqACo1IHtzuFACSUDisERYHDWBgAEEb4iYODnX2FQBfH9AA)).

#### Solution 1: Increase `printWidth` globally

Increase the `printWidth` value in `.prettierrc` to cover that line's character length (probably not the best idea, as it defeats the purpose of the option in your entire project).

#### Solution 2: Disable Prettier for line

Disable all Prettier rules for that particular line in `<template>`:

```html
<!-- eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier -->
<a href="https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-babel" rel="noopener" target="_blank">babel</a>
```

#### Solution 3: Increase `printWidth` for the component

Use a component-specific `printWidth` config in `<script>` that accommodates an acceptable length (currently no way to configure from `<template>`):

```html
<script>
/* eslint "prettier/prettier": ["warn", { "printWidth": 200 }] */
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry to say, and don't take it personal, but all this suggestions are ugly workarounds and not solutions. If the print width must be increased, the code will by less readable. If prettier has to be disabled everywhere it make nonsense, the code again will be less readable. Just looking at the fact that closing tags need two lines, I wonder in which case this makes any sense at all. If there is really no solution for this, Prettier in my eyes is unsuitable for HTML. I'll have to see if I can exclude HTML but have JavaScript in VUE files included...

Comment: Yes, these are indeed workarounds because there is no other way to achieve the formatting you want with Prettier and ESLint. Perhaps I should change the wording from "solution" to "option". Prettier doesn't need to be disabled everywhere; you could disable it for a specific line in your template. If you find yourself having to disable it for many lines, then you might reach for a wider scope (component level or global).

Answer (score 0):

```
'prettier/prettier': [
  'warn',
  {
    singleQuote: true,
    parser: 'flow', // Bingo
    semi: false,
    printWidth: 80,
    trailingComma: 'none',
    endOfLine: 'auto'
  }
],
```